# Django(3.2) не находит js

Tags: django

`"GET /static/js/SmoothScroll.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1682` . Причём css с той же `/static/css/` работает.
Подключил так: `<script src={% static "js/SmoothScroll.js" %}></script>` . Миграции выполнены, коллектстатик тоже. Только начал в django, так что ответ может быть очевидным, но гугл не помог, а делал вроде всё по документации.
Сервер локальный, запущен через `manage.py runserver`.

`settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testsite/static')
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Абсолютный путь к файлу: `"E:\type49\python\django\testsite\static\js\SmoothScroll.js"`

Ещё раз повторю, что css файл с путём `"E:\type49\python\django\testsite\static\css\style.css"` без проблем подключается.

Comment: Добавьте информацию про сервер. Это локальный сервер через `runserver` или  нет ? Обычно помогает в `settings.py` включить директорию со статикой.

Comment: да, локальный через `runserver`. В `settings.py` всё прописано, статикрут, статик урл.

Comment: отлично, где лежит сам файл (путь) и что указано в settings.py относительно static можете написать

Comment: @Дмитрий обновил вопрос.

Comment: при разработке вполне должно хватать `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. В `INSTALLED_APPS` должно быть подключено `django.contrib.staticfiles`. А, так же попробуйте подключить js скрипт в конце html страницы.

Comment: @Дмитрий `django.contrib.staticfiles` был подключен там изначально, по умолчанию. Пробовал и в конце подключать. Всё равно `GET /static/js/SmoothScroll.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1682`

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testsite/static')]` вот это удалить. Положить js файл в папку `static`, которая расположена в папке где лежит `settings.py`

Comment: Да, кинул туда, куда вы сказали и сделал `manage.py collectstatic` - сработало. Добавьте этот вариант в ответы - я отмечу как правильный. А для чего удалять переменную `STATICFILES_DIRS` ?

Comment: Необходимо удалить в `settings.py`:
```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testsite/static')
]
```
согласно [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/) это применятся для подключения статических ресурсов, не привязанных к конкретному приложению. Необходимо распологать `static` папку рядом с `settings.py`. **Данное решения подходит при разработке, при деплое на живой сервер могут быть изменения**

Comment: @type49 ее не обязательно удалять, просто нужен был `collectstatic`. Ответ выбран неверный

Comment: @ZaArs могу поспорить, что `collectstatic` может вообще не использоваться... При разработке на локальном сервере я никогда не использую данную функцию. Указание на документацию не достаточно вам? Вам нужен перевод? В моем ответе четко указано, что при деплое ответ не корректен.

Comment: @Дмитрий приведите цитату из источника, пожалуйста

Comment: @ZaArs откройте [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/). В пункте Configuring static files указана примерная последовательность для конфигурации статических файлов. И четко указано, что `STATICFILES_DIRS` используется для поиска статических файлов в данных директориях, которые могут не относиться к определенному приложению. Далее, листайте ниже в пункт Testing, Deployment. Только здесь появляется упоминание о `collectstatic`. И вот вам описание [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic). Разберетесь?

Comment: @Дмитрий убедили

Comment: @ZaArs спасибо, что отписали. Я не использую `collectstatic` при разработке, чтобы не плодить и так большое количество файлов. Все таки мой ответ решал вопрос ТС, был конкретным и я не хотел углубляться в пояснения. Поскольку я не вижу структуры проекта, я уточнил на каком этапе находится проект и дал ответ, который бы решил проблему на 95%